# How to create method that searches arrayList for the given parameters

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean

I am trying to create a method that returns true if the two parameters (user-inputted) are in the arrayList. When my code runs it always returns false when it should be true

```
public boolean containsItem(String targetTitle, String targetAuthor){
     boolean result= false;
     for (MediaItem contains : itemList) {
      if(contains.getTitle().equals(targetTitle) && contains.getAuthor().equals(targetAuthor)) {
        result = true;
      }else{
         result = false;
      }
     }
     return result;
  }
```

Do I need two separate if statements or loops? I am not sure why it keeps returning false. I have also tried `if(contains.equals(targetTitle) && contains.equals(targetAuthor)) {`

Comment: You need to `break` the loop after you find the search item, otherwise `result` can revert back to false at a later point in the loop.

Comment: yes that worked thank you!

Comment: Look at azros answer

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `result = false` part, if you find at a moment, just keep to true and that's it. Also to get quicker, when you find a true : just stop, no need to continue, so you can use a `break` to stop looping, or just `return` directly :

```
public boolean containsItem(String targetTitle, String targetAuthor){
    for (MediaItem contains : itemList) {
        if(contains.getTitle().equals(targetTitle) && contains.getAuthor().equals(targetAuthor)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean containsItem(String targetTitle, String targetAuthor){
 boolean result= false;
 for (MediaItem contains : itemList) {
  if(contains.getTitle().equals(targetTitle) && contains.getAuthor().equals(targetAuthor)) {
    result = true;
    break;
 }
 return result;
}
```

Not sure what getTitle() means here, and if it should be equalsIgnoreCase() is up to you, but this should work.